How do I create a Simple Marker Symbol based on distance in the ArcGIS Map JS SDK?
Using the ArcGIS Map JS SDK, I created a map with a simple marker symbol created on map click. Here is the code:
require(["esri/Map", "esri/views/MapView", "esri/Graphic", "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer"], (Map, MapView, Graphic, GraphicsLayer) => {
        map = new Map({
            basemap:  "streets-vector"
        });
        
        const view = new MapView({
            container: "map_details",
            map: map,
            zoom: 16,
            center: [INIT_COORDINATES.LNG, INIT_COORDINATES.LAT]
        });
        
        graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
        map.add(graphicsLayer);
        
        view.when(() => {
            view.on("click", (event) => {
                pointGraphic = new Graphic({ 
                    geometry: { 
                        type: "point", 
                        longitude: event.mapPoint.longitude, 
                        latitude: event.mapPoint.latitude
                    }, 
                    symbol: { 
                        type: "simple-marker", 
                        size: 50, // how do I set it to 50 meter ? Its unit is pt now 
                        color: [226, 119, 40, 0.5] 
                    }
                }); 
                graphicsLayer.add(pointGraphic);
            });
        });
    });

How do I set it to 50 meter ? Its unit is pt now. Currently, the marker symbol is still 50pt no matter what is the zoom level. I expect the marker will adjust the size based on the zoom level (i.e. always 50 meter)
On the other hand, how do I set the language of the map? I tried to use:
map = new Map({
    basemap:  "streets-vector",
    language: "es"
});

but the map is still showing English language.

the width is the width on the screen. 50 metres would be a little bit big to fit on your screen - you probably want to draw some sort of polygon on the map instead

but how do I draw a polygon based on actual distance, i.e. meter?

you use real world points (latitude/longitude for example)

Actually, you probably want to use a Circle - where you can specify a centre point and a radius (in whatever units of measure is supported by that API - "feet" |"kilometers" |"meters" |"miles" |"nautical-miles" |"yards") - default is meters (note the American spelling of the unit of measurement that Americans don't know how to use)

Can you share with me an example of Circle? I found that GeometryEngine's Geodesic Buffer can use distance as well: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-geometryEngine.html#geodesicBuffer, but the implementation is too difficult.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-Circle.html

With @Jaromanda X's help in comments, here is my solution to use distance to display a marker:
// replace the "pointGraphic = new Graphic" line
const circleGeometry = new Circle({
    center: [event.mapPoint.longitude, event.mapPoint.latitude],
    geodesic: true,
    numberOfPoints: 100,
    radius: 50, // 50m
    radiusUnit: "meters"
});
                
view.graphics.add(new Graphic({
    geometry: circleGeometry,
    symbol: {
        type: "simple-fill",
        color: [226, 119, 40, 0.5]          
    }
}));

